# How to use single Azure VM username and password to all Azure VMs across subscription level using Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have stored Azure VM username and password in Azure Key vaults. I am able to use VM username and password only within a Resource group but I want to use same Azure VM username and password other resource groups or Subscription level. I tried to to give role assignment and permissions but unable to use. Can you please help me on that.
[image: error]

[image: error1]

Comment: Can you please help me

Comment: What do you mean `use`? Could you elaborate on your issue a bit more? Maybe some links you referred to or something you have tried?

Comment: I have created Azure VM using ARM template. I was stored Azure VM login username and password in Azure Key Vaults.  I am creating multiple Azure VMs in multiple Resource group. So i want to use same Azure VM login username and password which i was stored earlier in Azure key vaults.

Comment: Within in a resource group i am able to use same login username and password to other VMs but when i am trying to use other resource group facing issue

Comment: error is: KeyVaultParameterReferenceNotFound: The specified KeyVault '/subscriptions/subscriptionid/resourceGroups/name/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/user3' could not be found

Comment: If I want to use same username and password to other resource groups also, which i was stored in key vaults  then how can i do

Comment: I was assign roles in IAM and access policies also but facing issue. Can you please help me on this

Comment: Did you give the role to your account used to deploy template in IAM at `subscription scope`?

Comment: I have given role to my account. i have shared screenshot in my question. check once.

Comment: I added screenshot. I was created key vault in one resource group. Now i need to same key vault to other resource groups

Comment: Did you reference secrets with static ID?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli#reference-secrets-with-static-id

Comment: And in your screenshot, your keyvault named `user2`, but in your error above, it is `user3`, I suppose you used the wrong name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your screenshot, your keyvault named `user2`, but in your error above, it is `user3`, I suppose you used the wrong name, when [reference the keyvault resource id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli#reference-secrets-with-static-id) in the template, you need to make sure your keyvault name is correct.